# how to parse docx xml using JDOM to extract the data from docx

Tags: xml, parsing, docx, jdom

since we can see all the XML files by opening the docx file using a winzip or winrar tool..i want to extract the data from those xml files..my questions are..
1. How to first extract all the XML files of a docx document using a code?
2. How shall i proceed with parsing since the actual data is present inside word/document.xml?

I am new to DOM and xml parsing please help me out...

Comment: You might instead consider a higher level API such as (in the Java world) docx4j or POI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write you the code, but the steps you will have to do are:

- Read the docx file
- Unzip it
- Get The Contents of the 'word/document.xml' file
- Pass that content to JDOM

Please post a new question if your question becomes more specific

Comment: yes thank you..i have unzipped the word doc as you said using ZipinputStream and i have the 'word/document.xml' file with me...since i am totally new to JDOM can you please tell me how can i proceed with learning JDOM??..i have basic idea about DOM(that it gives a tree struct of an XML)..what should be my next step??

Comment: Ok great ! Just pass it's content to JDOM now

Comment: what is JDOM?? is it some jar file??

Comment: I don't programm Java but I guess you will have to include a JAR

Comment: ohk..alrighty then i'll google about JDOM..thanks for your help!